# How to show title of field created using xml_field module in drupal7?

Tags: xml, drupal-7, field

I have been working on a module in which I am using the [XML Field](http://drupal.org/project/xml_field) module as follows.

I have created one entity type with a field which is of type xml.

I have set this field to accept multiple values. For example, my entity looks like the following.

```
Entity (item description, body, Metadata(this is xml field with multiple value))
with data --> Item1 ('This is item 1', 'this is body', (

(

    <page>
       <title>metadata item 1</title>
       <description>this is item 1</description>
    </page>

)

(

    <page>
       <title>metadata item 2</title>
       <description>this is item 2</description>
    </page>

)
)
```

Now under field Metatdata I cannot see title for each XML data node.

As per module title has to be displayed using 
`hook_node_view_alter()`, but as I have started module development recently, I am not able implement this hook.

desire output of Metadata is:

```
**Metadata(xml):**

metadata item 1:  (<--- how to display these titles??)

This is item 1

metadata item 2: (<--- how to display these titles??)

This is item 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<field type="spacer" name="myspacer1" label="&lt;b&gt; metadata item 1 &lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer2" label="&lt;b&gt; metadata item 2 &lt;/b&gt;" />`